# How do I get email for a certain period?

Tags: python, imap

there's a form (pyqt5), i take date from it:

```
 def buttonclicked(self):
    since = self.Since.text()
```

Then I put that since here:

```
 result, data = mail.search(None, '(SINCE {since} )'.format(since=since))
```

Error is :

```
b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: SINCE 10-09-2019 '
```

Comment: The required date format is detailed here: [IMAP Search Command with date filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654043/imap-search-command-with-date-filter)

Comment: Try to paste in google translate: "Unsupported search criterion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date needs to match the following format:

```
imap.search(None, '(SINCE 10-Sep-2019)')
```

[SEARCH BEFORE/AFTER with Pythons imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621341/search-before-after-with-pythons-imaplib)

Comment: didn't help, same mistake b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: SINCE "10.10.2019" '

Comment: Try putting it in the format: imap.search(None, '(SINCE 10-Sep-2019)'). This just worked for me. The double quotes are not needed. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698415/php-imap-search-unseen-since-date-with-time

Comment: Don't you know this works: result, data = mail.search(None, '(SINCE "01-DEC-2019" BEFORE "17-DEC-2019")') and this doesn't?  result, data = mail.search(None, '(SINCE {since} BEFORE {til})'.format(since=since, till=till))

Comment: What are {since} and {till} coming out to be?

Comment: i take them from pyqt form:         since = self.Since.text().replace('.', '-')
        till = self.Till.text().replace('.', '-')

Comment: I'd imagine as long as those strings (since and till) are in the correct format, with the month as letters instead of numbers, it should work. I just tried this and it was fine: mytext = "01-DEC-2019"
imap.search(None, '(SINCE {since})'.format(since=mytext))